# How can you automatically check if one or more attribute is modified in sqlalchemy?

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I have the following class which is a sqlalchemy instance.

```
class Cloaker(db.Model):
  id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)

  status = db.Column(db.Enum(Status), default=Status.DIRTY)

  domain = db.Column(db.String(32), nullable=False)

  user = db.Column(db.String(32))
  company = db.Column(db.String(32))
```

I have a view function where my users can update a cloaker instance.

I want Cloaker.status to change IF Cloaker.domain is updated. If user/company is updated, do not change status.

### What's the best approach to implementing this checking?

Comment: sqlalchemy have some documentation on attribute events [here](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/events.html). You should be able to call a function/method to change the status when the domain is set.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer:

```
class Cloaker(db.Model):
  # Fields that will cause Status to change to dirty if modified.
  dirty_if_mutated = set(['domain'])

  id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)

  status = db.Column(db.Enum(Status), default=Status.DIRTY)

  domain = db.Column(db.String(32), nullable=False)
  user = db.Column(db.String(32))
  company = db.Column(db.String(32))

  def change_status_if_necessary(self):
    """Checks if any attributes from dirty_if_mutated is changed.
    If so, change status to Status.DIRTY.
    """
    inspr = inspect(self)
    attrs = class_mapper(self.__class__).column_attrs      # exclude relationships
    changed_attr_keys = set()

    for attr in attrs:
      hist = getattr(inspr.attrs, attr.key).history
      if hist.has_changes():
        changed_attr_keys.add(attr.key)

    if Cloaker.dirty_if_mutated.intersection(changed_attr_keys):
      self.status = Status.DIRTY


def change_status_if_necessary(mapper, connect, target):
  target.change_status_if_necessary()

listen(Cloaker, 'before_update', change_status_if_necessary)
```